# White or empty base layer to Leaflet with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, leaflet

I need to create a very simple map where I can draw simple objects to the users.

I want to realize it in leaflet with angularjs by using [leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) plugin in order to interact with the map. Here there is a code example:

```
{
  "baselayers": {
    "osm": {
      "name": "OpenStreetMap",
      "url": "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      "type": "xyz",
      "layerParams": {},
      "layerOptions": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to create an empty or white base layer and add a customized layer on it, but the **baselayers** attribute cannot be empty or undefined.

Which is the best way to create an empty or white baselayer?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?

Comment: Hi @schaefea I answered you hereunder. Hope it can be useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe not too smart but it works.
I just use a white image as base overlay, then I draw everything i need on it.

```
baselayers: {
    white: {
        name: 'White',
        type: 'imageOverlay',
        url: 'http://www.ledr.com/colours/white.jpg',
        bounds: [[-540, -960], [540, 960]],
        layerParams: {
            noWrap: true,
            attribution: 'Creative Commons image found <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/c32/8025422440/">here</a>'
        }
    }
}
```

The bounds are referred to the 0, 0 coordinates in the center of the world, but it doesn't matter since my aim is to draw objects unreleated to the world map. 
Hereunder a picture of my self-drawn map.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that works. I was hoping for a solution that didn't need to use any images to reduce hits on the server. It turned out that my scope was changed so that I didn't need to do this anymore but thanks for sending the answer.

Comment: If you don't need to pan the map, you could (if you will need to do it again) avoid to using the image and set bounds in a place where there is nothing, as the ones in my example. It works as well.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing. But your image is a massive 24kb :).  I'm using a single clear pixel weighing in at 68b.